# Getting Error while decrypting string

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I am getting an error while decrypting and encrypted string:

> 5duOH+Tlg5deIrWZiHoNaQ==wVxXSl9pFu6A8h14/nLdyBkDzO4xmec7PQ0cB7MHjCDqhSRum3C7I1OfqL1rEWbNonU/ayCaJS18zV7ivQQU7A==MBJzKMrrrbmc2/vBZSPDkQ==I09Kj25UO+LcmRzgoqTT2g==+Fkm9VCGplEK6eEyHyEtuEodKSbckC07M2FShu2ukCg=

Error is as follows:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

My encryption code is:
    public string EncryptQueryString(string inputText, string key, string salt)
    {
        byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputText);

```
    using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        PasswordDeriveBytes secretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt));
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16)))
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());

            // Generate a string that won't get screwed up when passed as a query string.
            string urlEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64);
            return urlEncoded;
        }
    }
}
```

Decryption:

```
public string DecryptQueryString(string inputText, string key, string salt)
{
    byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes secretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt));

    using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged())
    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16)))
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        byte[] plainText = new byte[encryptedData.Length];
        cryptoStream.Read(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
        string utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
        return utf8;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be that you though this was a code writing service

Comment: What's the error? How did you encrypt the string? How are you trying to decrypt the string? Seriously - we need more information!!

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre A psychic code-writing service at that!!

Comment: iam getting error like "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Comment: @rahulkadachira Ok - please can you produce an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us to help you?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong, it's not a valid Base64 string. What more do you need to know?

Comment: It's all there. You suppose the string to be base64 but it's not. This is what the error says. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: public string EncryptQueryString(string inputText, string key, string salt)
       {
           byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputText);

           using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged())
           {
               PasswordDeriveBytes secretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt));
               using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16)))
               {

Comment: Edit code into your question, don't put it in comments.

Comment: How to solve it

Comment: @rahulkadachira did you write this code?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre We both know he didn't as anyone who wrote their own encryption code would not be using RijndaelManaged...

Comment: No, I copied from somewhere

Comment: @rahulkadachira Right, and so have you tried asking the person who wrote the code originally why it isn't working?

Comment: @Equalsk I know, it was kind of rhetorical I guess ;)

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is that he UrlEncodes the entire encrypted string which totally fudges it. Sounds like he needs to put the opposite UrlDecode in his decryption method. Can't be bothered to test it.

Comment: @Equalsk That looks plausible

Answer (score 2):

Base64 padding consists of `=` or `==`, and so it looks like multiple Base64 strings where appended together somehow. You'll have to find where they all originally ended, split them there, and try again.

Note that Base64 strings do not *always* have padding, only when it is needed, so there may even need to be breaks in places that you cannot see here.